# TeamCity: class is public, should be declared in a file named .java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, teamcity

I'm diving in TeamCity CI and was trying to start application on it I was faced with a Compilation Failure:

> [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
>   C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e94ee25852cea742\src\main\java\voc\ps\dao\WordDao.java:[7,7] error: class WordDAO is public, should be declared in a file named WordDAO.java

I'm running TeamCity locally on Windows 10. Version is:

> TeamCity Professional 9.1.7 (build 37573)
>   JDK: jdk1.8.0_91

Project is a standard Spring MVC + hibernate + Maven application.

However it works locally in IDEA and no any compilation failure is thrown.
Other interesting detail is failure is thrown against an interface.

First I added an auto-detected step, which included clean ant test maven goals.
After I split them. So it fails on the second step during compilation phase.

Build step settings:

> Runner type : Maven
>   Step name: test
>   Execute step: If all previous steps finished successfully
>   Goals: test
>   Path to POM file: pom.xml
>   Maven selection: Default
>   JDK: JDK 1.8

All other fields are empty or unchecked.

There is [full logs](http://www.filedropper.com/vockyjettyrun3) from TeamCity:

Nothing special, but I'm attaching it for completeness of the issue.

There is class, or to be more specific, interface which TeamCity doesn't like (copied exactly from the file which was generated by TeamCity):

**WordDAO.java**

```
package voc.ps.dao;
import voc.ps.model.Word;
import java.util.List;

public interface WordDAO {

    void addWord(Word p);
    void updateWord(Word p);
    List<Word> listWords();
    Word getWordById(int id);
    Word getWordByWord(String wordValue);
    void removeWord(int id);
}
```

So somebody can help me with this problem?
If you want to see more code of the application, you can find it on [gitHub](https://github.com/RockChild/Vocky)

Comment: Despite what the text of your question says, the file containing your class is named `WordDao.java`, not `WordDAO.java`. Case matters.

Comment: The problem was that locally I had WordDAO.java, but on gitHub it was WordDao.java and I don't really realize why? Yes, first this file was named WordDao, but later I renamed it according to other DAO files. Why it wasn't renamed on repository is a question?

Comment: A question, yes. But a different question. Probably because you're using a case insensitive OS like Windows.

Comment: Haven't heard about 'case insensitive OSes':)
Thanks! Now it works!